# Dutch localization (date, etc.) in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, localization, cakephp-2.1

I have already used `setLocale(LC_TIME, "nl_NL")` and `setLocale(LC_ALL, "nl_NL")` in `bootstap.php` file and none of them seem to work. Please note that I don't want to translate anything(this is what I came across a lot when searching for this), because the website will be completely in Dutch. I just want localization, including for example names of months and other stuff. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: is it a linux system? without any more details its hard to give you any real advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the return value of setlocale()? It will work only if the locale you are trying to set is actually available on your server. Use `locale -a` in terminal to check available locales. Also check [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#localization-in-cakephp) for how localization is done in Cake. You can use the TimeHelper and NumberHelper for localized time and currency. The TimeHelper needs the LC_TIME file for your locale.